# How to Derive Population Variance of AR(1) Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

If I have a process of the form $Y_t=\mu+\phi Y _{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, how is the population variance derived? Assuming that $\epsilon_t$ has a zero mean and a variance of 2.

Comment: Go down recursively to find an expression of Yt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that $|\phi|<1$, you can do backwards substitution to arrive at
$$
Y_t=\mu(1+\phi+\phi^2+\cdots)+\epsilon_t+\phi\epsilon_{t-1}+\cdots=\frac{\mu}{1-\phi}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\phi^j\epsilon_{t-j}.
$$
From here, you can compute
$$
\text{Var}(Y_t)=E\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\phi^j\epsilon_{t-j}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\phi^j\epsilon_{t-j}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\phi^{2j}E(\epsilon_{t-j}^2)=\frac{\text{Var}{\epsilon}}{1-\phi^2}=\frac{2}{1-\phi^2}.
$$
The second equality uses the fact that when the indices don't match, the expectation vanishes. Finally, if your process doesn't start at infinity in the past, you need to **define** $\text{Var}(Y_0)$ as $\frac{\text{Var}{\epsilon}}{1-\phi^2}$.